# C++ object of type class only accessing one print fucntion

Tags: c++, class

In this program there are two functions named display, each manipulate different types of data which getw called into main by objects.

```
#include<string> 
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std; 


class Hat { 
  private:
    string type;
    char size; 
  public:
    void display();
    Hat(string type, char size);

};

Hat::Hat(std::string _type, char _size):
  type(_type),
  size(_size)
{

}

void Hat::display()
{
    cout << "Hat type   : " << size << endl; //arrows wrong way
    cout << "Hat size   : " << type << endl; //missing ending cout <<
}

class Person { 
  public:
    string name;
    unsigned int idNum;
     Hat myHat;
    void display();
     Person(string,char,string,int);


};

Person::Person(string _name, char hat_size, string hat_type, int _idNum): 

name(_name), idNum(_idNum), 
myHat(hat_type,hat_size)
{

}

void Person::display()
{
        cout << "Given name : " << name << endl;
        cout << "Id. number : " << idNum << endl;

}

int main() 
{

    Person personA("Alice",'M',"Trilbee",12321);
    Person personB("Bob",'S',"Ferret",2324);
    personA.display();
    personB.display();

  return 0;
}
```

The expected outcome of this program would be

```
Given name : Alice
Id. number : 12321
Hat type : Beret
Hat size : M
Given name : Bob
Id. number : 2324
Hat type : S
Hat size : Trilby
```

But instead the output is

```
Given name : Alice
Id. number : 12321
Given name : Bob
Id. number : 2324
```

The objects declared in main, used to access the display functions, are only accessing the one found in the persons class and not the hat class and im unsure why.

Comment: Why do you think that `Person::display()` calls `Hat::display()` implicitly? The classes (themselves) are unrelated to each other. That one is the type of a member variable of the other isn't relevant in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly call `display` member function of your `Hat` class (myHat) in `Person::display()`. Try this:

```
void Person::display()
{
    cout << "Given name : " << name << endl;
    cout << "Id. number : " << idNum << endl;
    myHat.display();
}
```

After this, the output would be:

```
Given name : Alice
Id. number : 12321
Hat type   : M
Hat size   : Trilbee
Given name : Bob
Id. number : 2324
Hat type   : S
Hat size   : Ferret
```

Comment: If it has solved your problem, don't forget to upvote and accept the answer.